# Data binding controls in asp.net

Tags: controls, asp.net-3.5

I have to display a set of data in the following manner:

[image: Data Listing]

Which ASP.NET 3.5 control best matches my requirement?

If one matches, could you please give me an idea about how to format it to view like the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off you have multiple blocks (multiple rows) so I would suggest a Repeater. Within each block you must display three columns (the image the text and the small images), and you should use a Panel (renders as a ). In the second panel you have multiple lines of text for which you can use Labels because they allow for rendering as a  so that you an include a class.

Style everything nicely with CSS and you should be able to remake the above picture.

Comment: Is there any chance to format `GridView` as in the picture, because we use `GridView` every where in our project and wrote so many supporting classes (like paging).

Answer (score 1):

I think repeater control would be fine for your requirement.