# Variable number of columns with Repeater control ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater, dynamic

One of pages contains a `Repeater` control. Earlier, I bind a static number of columns to the repeater. For example, my stored procedure will return Name,Age,Salary,Phone,DOB of an employee. So I could use like the following

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <asp:Label ID="lblSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Salary")%>' ToolTip="Salary"></asp:Label>
   </td>
 </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Now** I want to change the design. I have a settings page and I will say which columns should be listed here. Some time I need to list only Name and Age etc. So I can not hard code the design of `Repeater`. What is the best way to handle the situation ? Is it good to dynamically add labels to the item template?

Comment: Can you consider `DataGrid` in your case? It would be easier to manipulate variable number of columns

Comment: I can NOT use `DataGrid`. I need custom design.

Comment: Ohkie. How can I do it with `DataGrid` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a GridView with TemplateFields. Depending on the settings you show or hide the columns. Here you find a [documentation of the TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx).

EDIT: Another control with more flexibility than Repeater is the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx).

If you want to use the Repeater Control you can use placeholders to turn on and off single columns. Just put every column into a PlaceHolder and turn on and off the visibility. Instead of a PlaceHolder you can of course use a UserControl as well.

EDIT 2: Solution with PlaceHolder could look like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <tr> 
  <asp:PlaceHolder Visible="<%# IsSalaryVisible %>" runat="server"> 
     <td> 
       <asp:Label ID="lblSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Salary")%>' ToolTip="Salary"></asp:Label> 
     </td> 
   </asp:PlaceHolder>
  <asp:PlaceHolder Visible="<%# IsNameVisible %>" runat="server"> 
     <td> 
       <asp:Label ID="lblSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' ToolTip="Salary"></asp:Label> 
     </td> 
   </asp:PlaceHolder>
  </tr> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Please. I can not use any controls other than `Repeater` :( . Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397078/data-binding-contorls-in-asp-net

Comment: what is the reason why you HAVE to use the repeater? I tried to give you some more options (see my answer)

Comment: Ohhh. Should I change my design too ?

Comment: You don't have to change the (HTML) design. You just use a different server control to generate your HTML.

Comment: Well. I decided to use Repeater with PlaceHolder. Could you please elaborate your answer in the context of PlaceHolder ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to have a user control for each field that may be displayed. Whether the same user controls for all the field that is configurable or a separate control for each field. Then when you bind the repeater you can set the `Visible` property of the control accordingly.

Is that the direction you wanted to go?

Comment: if rauf can only use a repeater this is the only way to go.. +1